# Preserving accentuated letters when running a PERL script from linux terminal

Tags: linux, perl, unicode, non-ascii-characters

I want to get a plain text file from the French Wikipedia dump XML file.
To that end, I am applying a Perl script

I can give the full file if necessary, I only added the line

```
tr/a-zàâééèëêîôûùç-/ /cs;
```

to the script here: http://mattmahoney.net/dc/textdata.html

However, when I run on linux terminal:

```
perl filterwikifr.pl frwiki.xml > frwikiplaintext.txt
```

the output text file does not print accentuated letters correctly. For example, I get catÃ©gorie instead of catégorie...

I also tried:

```
perl -CS filterwikifr.pl frwiki.xml > frwikiplaintext.txt
```

without better success (and other variants instead of `-CS...`)

Comment: The concept of "plain text" doesn't really exist. The output file must be encoded in some format. Do you really mean you only want 7-bit ASCII output?

Comment: I only want that accentuated letters stay preserved (and I guess the output should be in UTF-8, but I am not a specialist of unicode). If I open the file with LibreOffice, it works, but with the text editor, it prints weird characters.

Comment: What are the contents of `$LANG` and `env | grep LC_`?

Comment: What "text editor" are you using? If LibreOffice is reading it, then most likely the output file is correct.

Comment: I am using gedit in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: output of env | grep LC_   LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8

Comment: I meant `echo $LANG`.

Comment: output of echo $LANG  : en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Why are you running `perl filename.xml`? It should call your Perl script not the xml file. `perl perlscript.pl`.

Comment: If you do this `echo 'tr/a-zàâééèëêîôûùç-/ /cs;' > foo.txt` followed by `perl -p -e 'tr/a-zàâééèëêîôûùç-/ /cs;' < foo.txt`, do you see `tr a-zàâééèëêîôûùç- cs` as output?

Comment: @ChankeyPathak yes, you are right

Comment: @b4hand yes, i see tr a-zàâééèëêîôûùç- cs

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with the text editor gedit.

If, instead of opening the file directly, I open gedit, and then go to "open" and down, in "Character encoding", I choose UTF-8 instead of "Automatically Detected", then the accents are printed correctly.